# javascript: function generation based on object's attributes which are contained in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate objects containing functions that are using other object attributes. It's a bit difficult to explain so let me give an example:

I've written that code:

```
var myarray = [
    {name: "n1"},
    {name: "n2"},
    {name: "n3"},
    {name: "n4"},
    {name: "n5"},
];
var printers = [];
for (index=0;index<5;index++) {
    var obj = myarray[index];
    printers[index] = {
        myfunc : function(titi, tata) {
            console.log("name: " + obj.name);
        }
    }
}
for (index=0;index<printers.length;index++) {
    printers[index].myfunc();
}
```

When I execute the code, I get that result:

```
name: n5
name: n5
name: n5
name: n5
name: n5
```

What I need is:

```
name: n1
name: n2
name: n3
name: n4
name: n5
```

I would be glad if someone out there could help me understand how you can manage this in javascript.

Comment: Great link Juhana, you made my day, I did not come accross that question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
printers[index] = {
    myfunc : function (name) {
       return function(titi, tata) {
        console.log("name: " + name);
       }
    }(obj.name)
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/wavoje/1/edit?js,console)